# epos_hardware_node can't find parameters

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
i tryed to get the epos_hardware package ti work.
I have the right parameter in the yaml file and if i started the launch file directly with `roslaunch mrd.launch` it initalized the motors and I can send with the velocity commad the velocity to one motor.

But when i wnat to start it with the epos_hardware_node like it is told at the wiki I get

```
ae@AErobotNUC:~$ rosrun epos_hardware epos_hardware_node actuator_right
[ INFO] [1475145806.123784737]: Loading EPOS: actuator_right
[ERROR] [1475145806.133245540]: You must specify an actuator name
[ERROR] [1475145806.135072354]: You must specify a serial number
[ERROR] [1475145806.137558224]: You must specify an operation mode
[ INFO] [1475145806.137672590]: 
[ INFO] [1475145806.230669194]: Waiting for robot_description
```

I think that the problem is that the node doesn't get the parameter and so i tryed to start first the launch and then the node i get his

```
ae@AErobotNUC:~$ rosrun epos_hardware epos_hardware_node left
[ INFO] [1475146396.731178459]: Loading EPOS: left
[ERROR] [1475146396.739065881]: You must specify an actuator name
[ERROR] [1475146396.741005635]: You must specify a serial number
[ERROR] [1475146396.742883926]: You must specify an operation mode
[ INFO] [1475146396.743017379]: 
[ INFO] [1475146396.854288335]: Initializing Motors
[ERROR] [1475146396.854556155]: Not Initializing: 0x0, initial construction failed
[ERROR] [1475146396.854641495]: Could not configure motor: left
[FATAL] [1475146396.854699196]: Failed to initialize motors
```

I'm new at ROS and didn't unterstand the problem, thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244735/epos_hardware_node-can%27t-find-parameters/) by [Milliau](https://answers.ros.org/users/27715/milliau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a further review on the example launch file and fully understand what does. It calls the urdf and yaml yes and load them to the parameter server, But also calls epos_harware_node, without having more information about your launch file, urdfs and yamls it is a bit difficult to predict what is wrong.

Before I would be also check the output on list_devices node and be sure that everything is being detected, for further help you should specify more about the contex of your problem (devices etc)

---

Originally posted by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) with karma: 136 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1